# D3.js path goes in different directions in V3 vs V4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to make the same multi-line graph in D3 V3 and V4, but they behave differently for reasons I don't understand. What can I change in my V4 code that will make the paths connect in the correct order (according to the x axis instead of the y axis)?

Here's what V3 gives, taken from the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nancynancy/kmdgrm29/8/)  I made for it:

[image]

...But here's V4:

[image]

Jsfiddle doesn't support V4 yet, so here's my code:

```
var margin = {top: 20, right: 40, bottom: 100, left: 100},
width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.depth); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.carat); });

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

d3.csv("diamonds.csv", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.carat = +d.carat;
  d.depth = +d.depth;
  //d.cut = +d.cut;
})

data.sort(function(a,b) { return a.x - b.x; });

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.depth; })).nice();
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.carat; })).nice();

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("x", 5)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(45)")
    .style("text-anchor", "start")

    var dataNest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) {return d.cut;})
    .entries(data);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Price");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
                return d.color = color(d.key); })
    .attr("d", line(d.values));
        });

});
```

Comment: You **can** use D3 v4 in Fiddle, just put this in the HTML panel: `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: I tried to have a look at your fiddle, but the link is broken.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I fixed the link. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at your code using D3 v3.x, you did this after loading the data:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x = +d.depth;
    d.carat = +d.carat;
})
```

And using that property `x` for sorting:

```
data.sort(function(a,b) { return a.x - b.x; });
```

However, in your v4.x version, you did:

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.depth = +d.depth;
    d.carat = +d.carat;
})
```

And used an nonexistent `x` for sorting (the problem with sorting alone was making the lines different from v3.x).

**Solution**: use `depth` for sorting:

```
data.sort(function(a,b) { return a.depth - b.depth; });
```

Here is your code using v4.x version:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 40,
    bottom: 100,
    left: 100
  },
  width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(d.depth);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.carat);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var data = d3.csvParse(d3.select("pre#data").text());

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.carat = +d.carat;
  d.depth = +d.depth;
  //d.cut = +d.cut;
})

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.depth - b.depth;
});

x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.depth;
})).nice();
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.carat;
})).nice();

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("x", 5)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(45)")
  .style("text-anchor", "start")

var dataNest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.cut;
  })
  .entries(data);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Price");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

dataNest.forEach(function(d) {
  svg.append("path")
    .attr("class", "line")
    .style("stroke", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
      return d.color = color(d.key);
    })
    .attr("d", line(d.values));
});
```

```css
pre {
  display:none;
  }

path
{
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
//  stroke: green;
//  stroke-width: 3.5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<pre id="data">
carat,cut,color,clarity,depth,table,price,x,y,z
0.41,Ideal,G,VS1,60.8,56,899,4.79,4.82,2.92
0.3,Ideal,F,VS1,62.1,55,612,4.31,4.35,2.69
1.25,Ideal,H,SI1,62.2,57,6661,6.86,6.9,4.28
0.41,Ideal,G,VS2,61.4,55,1061,4.8,4.75,2.93
0.53,Premium,E,VVS2,62.4,56,2331,5.19,5.17,3.23
1.14,Very Good,G,VS2,63.2,56,6435,6.67,6.63,4.2
0.51,Premium,G,SI1,62,59,1053,5.12,5.1,3.17
1.51,Good,H,VVS2,63.1,59,11826,7.26,7.28,4.59
1.31,Ideal,J,SI1,62.5,56,6337,6.95,7.04,4.37
0.33,Very Good,I,VVS1,61.7,61,608,4.43,4.45,2.74
0.42,Ideal,F,VS1,62.3,55,1103,4.79,4.77,2.98
1.01,Good,E,VS2,60.8,63,6250,6.44,6.46,3.92
1,Premium,F,SI1,62.7,59,5292,6.4,6.36,4
0.51,Ideal,G,VVS1,61.9,53,1919,5.14,5.2,3.2
0.34,Ideal,H,SI1,61.5,55,647,4.53,4.55,2.79
0.23,Premium,F,VVS2,61.3,59,445,3.94,3.99,2.43
0.3,Ideal,F,VS2,62.9,57,776,4.29,4.27,2.69
1.14,Premium,F,SI1,60.4,58,6320,6.82,6.79,4.11
0.33,Ideal,J,VVS1,62.1,54,509,4.45,4.47,2.77
0.41,Premium,H,SI1,60.9,60,683,4.79,4.83,2.93
2.01,Premium,J,SI2,62.8,58,12407,8.09,8,5.05
2.01,Very Good,I,SI1,60.3,59,15126,8.14,8.21,4.93
0.4,Very Good,D,VS2,62.8,58,993,4.66,4.71,2.94
1.09,Premium,D,SI1,61.6,58,5799,6.61,6.57,4.06
0.3,Ideal,F,VS1,61.5,55,612,4.31,4.34,2.66
0.77,Very Good,H,SI2,63.6,58,2129,5.77,5.81,3.68
0.38,Very Good,F,VS1,62.7,57,883,4.71,4.64,2.93
0.54,Premium,E,VS1,60.3,58,1939,5.26,5.32,3.19
0.93,Premium,F,SI1,58.8,60,4010,6.49,6.37,3.78
0.32,Ideal,H,VS1,61.1,56,561,4.44,4.46,2.72
0.78,Premium,F,SI2,62.8,56,2200,5.9,5.86,3.69
0.4,Ideal,E,VS1,61.2,55,1005,4.79,4.76,2.92
0.41,Ideal,D,VS2,62.4,55,1076,4.79,4.76,2.98
0.73,Very Good,E,SI1,61.6,59,2760,5.77,5.78,3.56
2.52,Very Good,G,SI2,63.2,58,17689,8.65,8.61,5.45
1.06,Ideal,D,VVS2,62,56,12053,6.53,6.57,4.06
0.8,Very Good,D,IF,63.3,57,6834,5.85,5.87,3.71
1.5,Premium,H,VS2,62.2,58,10291,7.27,7.36,4.55
2.17,Good,H,SI2,58.9,62,16036,8.48,8.52,5.01
1.58,Ideal,G,SI1,62.2,55,11927,7.44,7.5,4.65
2.03,Premium,H,VS2,62.1,56,18139,8.2,8.12,5.07
0.58,Very Good,D,SI2,62.9,56,1438,5.31,5.35,3.35
0.72,Very Good,D,VS2,62.1,59,3016,5.7,5.73,3.55
0.38,Ideal,D,VVS2,61.5,57,1200,4.63,4.67,2.86
0.5,Premium,E,VS2,61.3,60,1624,5.07,5.11,3.12
0.31,Ideal,F,VS2,61.1,56,640,4.35,4.39,2.67
1.41,Premium,D,SI2,61.1,56,6988,7.19,7.15,4.38
0.7,Good,I,VS1,63.2,55,2274,5.58,5.63,3.54
1.22,Ideal,F,SI2,62,57,4852,6.88,6.83,4.25
1.58,Ideal,H,VS2,61.4,56,12334,7.5,7.56,4.62
1.2,Ideal,G,VS1,62,55,9625,6.81,6.87,4.24
1.03,Premium,H,I1,61.1,60,3172,6.46,6.51,3.96
0.77,Very Good,H,VS1,62.8,58,2961,5.75,5.78,3.62
1.04,Ideal,I,VS2,61.5,57,5105,6.49,6.52,4
1,Good,H,SI1,63.7,60,4788,6.33,6.3,4.02
0.82,Very Good,G,IF,61.9,57,4844,5.96,6,3.7
0.71,Ideal,D,VS1,60.9,57,3518,5.74,5.76,3.5
1.21,Ideal,I,SI2,64.6,56,4879,6.67,6.62,4.29
0.4,Very Good,E,SI1,61.7,60,687,4.68,4.72,2.9
1.11,Premium,H,SI1,61.1,60,5433,6.68,6.62,4.06
1.5,Ideal,F,VS2,60.4,57,14071,7.41,7.43,4.48
1.48,Very Good,H,SI1,62.5,59,8815,7.16,7.23,4.5
0.28,Ideal,F,VVS2,61.5,57,787,4.19,4.24,2.59
0.64,Very Good,E,VS2,63.4,54,2114,5.52,5.49,3.49
1.68,Ideal,I,VS2,62.1,57,10800,7.6,7.54,4.7
0.93,Premium,G,SI2,61.7,60,3802,6.25,6.2,3.84
0.34,Very Good,E,SI1,62.9,56,596,4.45,4.48,2.81
1.57,Premium,G,VS1,59.9,56,14180,7.6,7.55,4.54
1.16,Premium,H,SI2,61.8,58,4872,6.81,6.75,4.19
0.3,Ideal,E,VVS2,61.4,57,1013,4.34,4.32,2.66
1.06,Very Good,F,SI1,63.4,58,5520,6.51,6.42,4.1
1.14,Ideal,H,SI1,61.6,56,7079,6.72,6.74,4.14
1,Premium,J,SI1,58.7,58,3920,6.55,6.51,3.83
2.01,Very Good,F,SI2,63.3,59,11925,7.98,7.89,5.02
1.37,Premium,G,VS1,58.3,60,10412,7.35,7.3,4.27
0.91,Premium,E,SI2,61.6,60,3846,6.14,6.1,3.77
1,Premium,G,VS2,63,58,6048,6.4,6.33,4.01
0.4,Good,G,SI1,63.4,58,655,4.66,4.71,2.97
1.39,Very Good,G,SI2,61.5,62,6628,7.09,7.16,4.38
0.31,Ideal,G,IF,62.7,57,924,4.31,4.34,2.71
1.5,Premium,H,VS2,62.4,59,11092,7.29,7.32,4.56
0.99,Very Good,F,SI1,62.5,58,5112,6.36,6.38,3.98
1.5,Very Good,I,VVS2,64,54,9618,7.19,7.27,4.63
1.04,Very Good,E,VVS2,62.4,58,8748,6.46,6.4,4.01
1.01,Premium,H,SI1,61.8,59,5204,6.38,6.33,3.93
0.71,Fair,D,SI1,55.5,62,2086,6,5.97,3.32
0.26,Ideal,G,VS1,62.1,55,478,4.09,4.12,2.55
0.92,Premium,E,SI1,61.7,57,4637,6.32,6.2,3.86
0.32,Ideal,E,VS2,61.8,54,768,4.43,4.4,2.73
0.54,Ideal,H,IF,61.5,54,1981,5.27,5.3,3.25
0.4,Ideal,G,IF,61.2,56,1199,4.74,4.77,2.91
1.28,Very Good,G,VVS2,59.5,56,11478,7.12,7.16,4.25
0.42,Premium,G,VS2,60.6,59,1087,4.85,4.78,2.92
1.04,Premium,H,VS2,60.4,59,5777,6.66,6.51,3.98
0.91,Premium,G,SI1,61.8,60,4045,6.18,6.21,3.83
0.33,Very Good,H,VS2,58.8,62,486,4.49,4.53,2.65
0.31,Ideal,E,VS1,61.3,54,664,4.37,4.4,2.69
0.61,Very Good,D,VS1,62.4,57,2096,5.44,5.46,3.4
0.3,Ideal,H,VVS2,61.6,55,605,4.3,4.34,2.66
1.57,Premium,J,VS1,61.3,59,8595,7.44,7.47,4.57
0.72,Very Good,J,VS1,62.3,57,2136,5.73,5.77,3.58
1.11,Premium,F,SI2,62.2,57,5284,6.67,6.61,4.13
0.4,Premium,D,SI2,61.7,58,855,4.74,4.69,2.91
0.7,Good,F,VVS1,63.3,56,3310,5.64,5.7,3.59
1,Premium,D,SI2,59.4,60,4626,6.56,6.48,3.87
0.61,Ideal,E,VVS2,62,54,3011,5.43,5.47,3.38
1,Premium,F,VS2,62.8,59,6328,6.35,6.32,3.98
1.05,Ideal,F,SI2,60.9,56,4591,6.56,6.64,4.02
1.01,Premium,I,SI1,61.6,58,3944,6.45,6.51,3.99
0.51,Ideal,F,VS2,63.2,57,1687,5.08,5.05,3.2
1.2,Premium,H,SI2,62.4,61,5040,6.81,6.78,4.24
1.52,Ideal,J,VS1,62.3,58,8608,7.32,7.35,4.57
0.51,Premium,F,VVS2,61.9,56,2310,5.17,5.13,3.19
0.5,Very Good,H,IF,61.4,61,1923,5.14,5.03,3.12
1.01,Premium,G,SI1,63,60,4118,6.34,6.3,3.98
0.8,Very Good,F,VS1,62.6,57,3720,5.9,5.98,3.72
2.01,Very Good,I,SI1,62.8,60,14811,7.99,8.04,5.03
1,Premium,E,SI1,61.6,59,5600,6.41,6.38,3.94
1,Good,J,VS1,58.1,64,3920,6.63,6.51,3.82
0.52,Premium,F,VS2,61.4,62,1605,5.19,5.16,3.18
1.3,Very Good,I,VS2,61.8,56,7087,6.98,7.04,4.33
2,Very Good,I,SI1,62.9,59.2,15081,7.95,8.08,5.05
0.31,Very Good,I,VS2,61.6,56,468,4.36,4.39,2.69
1.63,Very Good,I,SI1,62,54,9090,7.6,7.67,4.73
0.3,Premium,H,VVS2,62.1,52,776,4.31,4.29,2.67
1.1,Premium,G,VS2,62.8,58,6387,6.6,6.58,4.14
0.23,Very Good,F,VVS2,61,59,465,3.93,3.97,2.41
1.23,Premium,I,SI2,62.1,59,4773,6.83,6.79,4.23
1.02,Good,G,VS2,63.6,57,5816,6.38,6.41,4.07
0.71,Premium,F,VS1,59.2,58,2839,5.87,5.82,3.46
1.69,Ideal,H,I1,62,56,6757,7.66,7.61,4.73
1.6,Ideal,G,VS2,61.9,56,15000,7.53,7.47,4.64
0.32,Ideal,H,IF,61.9,54.2,783,4.38,4.42,2.72
0.73,Very Good,G,SI2,62.2,58,2057,5.71,5.77,3.57
0.32,Ideal,D,VS2,62.7,54,758,4.36,4.38,2.74
0.7,Ideal,E,VS2,61.1,59,3201,5.67,5.73,3.48
0.3,Ideal,H,VS1,62.1,54,526,4.32,4.35,2.69
0.9,Good,I,VS2,63.8,55,3303,6.07,6.16,3.9
0.52,Premium,H,SI2,60.9,61,975,5.15,5.1,3.12
0.97,Premium,F,SI1,62.7,59,4561,6.28,6.31,3.95
0.32,Very Good,H,SI1,62.6,55,461,4.37,4.38,2.74
0.54,Ideal,F,SI1,61.2,56,1307,5.23,5.29,3.22
1.21,Good,F,VS2,63.7,58,7911,6.67,6.71,4.26
1.51,Very Good,I,SI1,63.1,56,7891,7.28,7.33,4.61
1.01,Premium,F,VS2,58.9,58,6271,6.59,6.51,3.86
1.57,Very Good,J,VS2,62.6,59,7832,7.39,7.43,4.64
0.73,Premium,I,VS1,60.3,58,2371,5.83,5.87,3.53
1.2,Ideal,I,SI1,62.5,57,5107,6.77,6.71,4.21
3.04,Premium,I,SI2,59.3,60,18559,9.51,9.46,5.62
0.31,Very Good,G,VVS1,63.1,56,1046,4.35,4.33,2.74
0.5,Premium,E,I1,60.7,61,840,5.14,5.05,3.09
0.38,Ideal,I,VS1,62.4,54.4,703,4.62,4.66,2.9
1.12,Premium,G,VS2,60.7,53,6774,6.81,6.7,4.1
1.33,Premium,F,SI2,60.7,62,5288,7.12,7.07,4.31
1.11,Ideal,J,VS1,61.7,57,4854,6.67,6.72,4.13
0.71,Ideal,G,SI1,62.4,56,2386,5.74,5.71,3.57
1.03,Ideal,G,VS1,62.1,57,6558,6.44,6.47,4.01
0.32,Very Good,G,VVS1,61.4,55,772,4.41,4.45,2.72
1.55,Premium,D,VS2,61.5,58,16137,7.51,7.48,4.61
0.72,Premium,F,VS2,60.8,58,2530,5.78,5.74,3.5
0.31,Good,F,VS2,63.4,56,625,4.29,4.32,2.73
0.42,Ideal,G,IF,62,57,1310,4.82,4.8,2.98
2.1,Premium,H,SI2,60.4,59,16479,8.28,8.33,5.02
0.66,Ideal,H,VS2,61.4,56,2178,5.62,5.65,3.46
0.48,Premium,F,SI1,60.6,62,1110,5.06,5,3.05
0.91,Very Good,D,SI1,63,59,4429,6.11,6.15,3.86
0.5,Ideal,E,SI2,62.5,57,1154,5.04,5.07,3.16
0.57,Ideal,I,VS1,62.2,55,1448,5.28,5.33,3.3
1.09,Premium,F,SI1,60.9,59,5384,6.64,6.59,4.03
1,Premium,H,SI1,62.3,60,4788,6.38,6.34,3.96
0.4,Very Good,E,VS2,63,58,791,4.7,4.73,2.97
1.2,Ideal,I,SI1,60.1,56,5578,6.9,6.84,4.13
0.71,Premium,I,VS2,59.3,59,2300,5.89,5.81,3.47
0.34,Ideal,D,VS2,62,55,1033,4.48,4.45,2.77
1.25,Good,J,SI1,63.6,57,5110,6.86,6.81,4.35
0.41,Ideal,D,SI1,61.7,54,1015,4.79,4.78,2.95
0.51,Fair,D,SI2,66.5,58,1109,4.95,4.89,3.27
0.56,Ideal,E,SI1,62.7,57,1698,5.27,5.23,3.29
1.04,Ideal,G,VS1,61.5,57,7457,6.5,6.54,4.01
0.3,Ideal,I,SI1,61.9,57,422,4.29,4.31,2.66
0.5,Premium,F,VS2,61.7,60,1323,5.06,5.02,3.11
0.28,Very Good,G,VVS2,62.3,56,522,4.16,4.19,2.6
0.37,Very Good,E,VS1,62,56,925,4.59,4.63,2.86
0.8,Premium,F,SI2,58.5,62,2371,6.08,6.05,3.55
0.81,Very Good,F,SI2,62.7,58,2942,5.92,5.95,3.72
0.51,Ideal,E,VVS2,62.8,56,2211,5.13,5.15,3.23
0.98,Ideal,G,SI1,62.3,56,4665,6.37,6.34,3.96
1.51,Good,H,VS2,63.6,61,8904,7.08,7.03,4.49
0.5,Premium,D,SI1,60.3,58,1433,5.12,5.1,3.08
0.43,Ideal,F,VVS2,62.2,55,1250,4.85,4.83,3.01
0.7,Ideal,F,SI1,61.1,57,2516,5.75,5.71,3.5
0.3,Premium,E,SI1,61.8,60,675,4.28,4.23,2.63
0.7,Very Good,F,VS2,62.9,56,2400,5.66,5.73,3.58
0.92,Very Good,D,VS1,61.9,58,7544,6.19,6.24,3.85
2.57,Premium,J,SI1,63,58,18485,8.77,8.65,5.49
2.25,Ideal,I,SI2,60.7,56,11104,8.54,8.5,5.17
0.51,Ideal,G,VVS2,61.5,57,1875,5.13,5.18,3.17
1.05,Ideal,H,SI2,61.9,56,4504,6.49,6.56,4.04
0.3,Ideal,E,VS1,62.5,56,694,4.27,4.31,2.68
1.01,Premium,J,VS2,62.4,60,3296,6.45,6.35,3.99
</pre>
```